# How to adopt SD card as Internal Storage

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, internal-storage, external-sd, samsung-galaxy-j3

I currently own a Samsung J3 emerge with Android version 6.0.1 (Marshmallow). However, I cannot format my AD card as Internal as I do not have that option. I cam only format it as portable. What must I do?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Have you checked out our [adoptable-storage tag wiki](/tags/adoptable-storage/info), and the posts and articles linked to in it? It should cover most of your concerns here.

Answer (score 0):

Well the device may have option of using SD CARD as internal storage if it is marshmallow  or up ,as it was a feature introduced in ANDROID 6.0

---

Usually it can be found by
Method 1
SETTINGS<

---

Method 2
If Sd card is not inserted then insert it and a notification will appear  in notification panel that you want to SETUP or EJECT 
Select SET UP and it will present you option to format as internal storage 
Select it and you will get it done
(if sd card was inserted beforehand only just eject it and reinsert to get that notification )

---

Method 3.               #root required #
Download an app Root Essential
Grant Root Access
Go to storage tab
Select Adoptable storage
Proceed with instructions
And Now SD card will be used as internal storage